# Error 000725 importing Python (Arcpy) script into tool of standard toolbox?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arctoolbox, geoprocessing-framework, error-000725

I have created a Python script. When I run the script as a standalone by make this a hard set path instead of sys.argv[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLcoO.jpg), the script really runs fine.

When I import this script as a python tool box then I get the error at output workspace that dataset is already existed. But there is no dataset in the GDB. I have attached the error file and the script file as well. I think i have set up the parameters  right as well.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please do not be put off by me closing this question as a duplicate and then merging its answer with the earlier question because doing that helps direct future visitors to our site to one source of answers to the same question asked in different ways.